# Threshold value change on click of rangeSelector in HighStock graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to change the threshold value on click of rangeSelector in HighStock graph. 
Also, I need to change the line value inside PlotLines of y-axis.

I tried following code

```
xAxis: {    
                events:{
                    setExtremes: function(e) {
                       if (e.trigger == "rangeSelectorButton" && 
                            e.rangeSelectorButton.text == "1m"){
                                  // this.threshold = 20;
                                  alert("on click of 1m range selector");
                                  // for threshold value
                                  this.threshold=20;
                                  this.series[0].plotOptions.threshold=20;
                                   this.plotOptions[0].series[0].threshold=20;
                                   this.rangeSelector.clickButton(0, true);
                                // for changing the line value of plotLines
                                this.yAxis[0].plotLines[0].value=20;

                                            }
                                    },
                            }
            },
```

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/w6bzohgd/1/) for jsfiddle link

I have put some alert to test that click on rangeSelector is working fine. 
I tried to change the values but the chart is not getting updated.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside setExtremes, `this` references the `xAxis` object.  The `threshold` is on the `series` object, so you need to get a reference to the right series.

```
var series = this.chart.series[0];
```

Then, you need to `update` it with the new value.

```
series.update({threshold: threshold}, false);
```

I'm passing `false` for the `redraw` parameter, since we're also going to update the `plotLine`, and we'll only want to redraw once.

For the `plotLine`, you'll need a reference to the `yAxis`.

```
var yAxis = this.chart.yAxis[0];
```

And, then you'll need to pass the new `plotLine` settings to the `update` method.

```
 yAxis.update({
     plotLines: [{
        value: threshold,
        color: 'green',
        dashStyle: 'shortdash',
        width: 2,
        label: {
             text: 'Last quarter minimum'
        }
     }]
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w6bzohgd/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot, Barbara! Really appreciate your answer, especially the way you anwered it. I realised, I should be more logical while applying chages each time to get it working. Thanks, for your help